# TOP16 Ⅱのサンプルコードが何を表しているのかわかりません．

Tags: linux, c

当方プログラミング初心者です．
TOP16 Ⅱを使用してるのですが，いただいたサンプルコードがどのような実行結果になるのかがわかりません．
以下にサンプルコードを載せます．
わかる方がいたら教えていただけないでしょうか．

```
serial_io.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>



int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity)
{
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
                printf("error %d from tcgetattr", errno);
                return -1;
        }

        cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
        cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

        tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
        // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
        // as \000 chars
        tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
        tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                        // no canonical processing
        tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

        tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                        // enable reading
        tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
        tty.c_cflag |= parity;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
        {
                printf("error %d from tcsetattr", errno);
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
}

void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block)
{
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
                printf("error %d from tggetattr", errno);
                return;
        }

        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
                printf("error %d setting term attributes", errno);
}
```

```
serial_io.h

#ifndef _SERIAL_IO_H
#define _SERIAL_IO_H



void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block);
int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity);


#endif
```

```
top 16Ⅱ.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 




#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "serial_io.h"


#define BAUDRATE (B115200)


// The device can be found using command   "ls /dev/tty*"
//
#define DEVICE ("/dev/ttyUSB0")

// useful command to clear the terminal screen
//
#define clrscr() printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J")



//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read analog input and return the value
//
//
// port = serial device handle
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

double TOP16II_readAnalog(int port, int analog_input)
{
    int char_count = 0;
    double ret_value = 0.0;
    char buf[100];
    char sendString[20];


    // valid input number ?
    //
    if (analog_input < 1)
    {
        return(0.0);
    }
    if (analog_input > 8)
    {
        return(0.0);
    }


    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH);                       // Discards old data in the rx buffer
    sprintf(sendString, "#z%d\r", analog_input);
    write(port, sendString, 4);                    // send 4 character command  

    //printf("Write %s\n", sendString);  

    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH); 

    usleep (100000);                               // ** sleep enough to process and reply                      

    char_count = read(port, &buf, 10);             // read 10 character response   

    //printf("GOT %s\n", buf);        

    if (char_count == 10)
    {
        // correct number of characters received
        //
        buf[8] = 0 ;  
        ret_value = atof(&buf[1]);
    }   

    return(ret_value);    

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Set a digital output state
//
// on_off = the new setting
// port = serial device handle
//
// digital_output = the output to set
//
//
// Returns:
//
//  0 = success
//  < 0 = error
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

double TOP16II_setDigital(int port, int digital_output, int on_off)
{
    int char_count = 0;
    int ret_value = -1;
    char buf[50];
    char sendString[20];


    int output = 0 ;          // the new setting
    int mask = 1;             // what bits will be affected ?


    // valid output number ?
    //
    if (digital_output < 1)
    {
        return(-1);
    }
    if (digital_output > 8)
    {
        return(-1);
    }

    mask <<= (digital_output-1);     // set bit position for the output

    if (on_off == 1)
    {
        // turn the digital output ON
        //
        output = mask;          
    }



    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH);                       // Discards old data in the rx buffer

    // format string into 8 bit 'hex' numbers
    //

    //printf("%d  %d\n", output, mask);

    sprintf(sendString, "#%02x%02x\r",output, mask );
    write(port, sendString, 6);                    // send 4 character command  

    //printf("Write %s\n", sendString);  

    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH); 

    usleep (100000);                               // ** sleep enough to process and reply                      

    char_count = read(port, &buf, 5);             // read 5 character response   

    //printf("GOT %s\n", buf);        

    if (char_count == 5)
    {
        // correct number of characters received (>OK[CR][LF])
        //

        ret_value = 0;
    }   

    return(ret_value);    

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read digital inputs and return the value (8 bits)
//
// port = serial device handle
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

unsigned int TOP16II_readDigital(int port)
{
    int char_count = 0;
    unsigned int ret_value = 0;
    char buf[100];
    char sendString[20];


    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH);                       // Discards old data in the rx buffer
    sprintf(sendString, "#x%c\r",0);
    write(port, sendString, 4);                    // send 4 character command  

    //printf("Write %s\n", sendString);  

    tcflush(port, TCIFLUSH); 

    usleep (100000);                              // ** sleep enough to process and reply                       

    char_count = read(port, &buf, 5);             // read 5 character response   

    //printf("GOT %s\n", buf);        

    if (char_count == 5)
    {
        // correct number of characters received
        //
        buf[3] = 0 ;                              // null terminate the string
        ret_value = atoi(&buf[1]);
    }   

    return(ret_value);    

}




// -----------------------------------------------------


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;      
    char *portname = DEVICE;
    double analog_reading1 = 0.0;
    double analog_reading2 = 0.0;
    double analog_reading3 = 0.0;
    double analog_reading4 = 0.0;
    double analog_reading5 = 0.0;
    double analog_reading6 = 0.0;
    double analog_reading7 = 0.0;
    double analog_reading8 = 0.0;

    unsigned int digital_in = 0;


    int output_count = 1;


    int fd = 0 ;

    printf("Start\n");



    fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);


    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname, strerror (errno));
        return -1;
     }

    set_interface_attribs (fd, B115200, 0);     // set speed to 115,200 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
    set_blocking (fd, 0);                       // set no blocking



    // loop

    for(i = 0 ; i < 500; i++)
    {
        analog_reading1 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 1);
        analog_reading2 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 2);
        analog_reading3 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 3);
        analog_reading4 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 4);
        analog_reading5 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 5);
        analog_reading6 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 6);
        analog_reading7 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 7);
        analog_reading8 = TOP16II_readAnalog(fd, 8);

        digital_in = TOP16II_readDigital(fd);


        clrscr();      // clear the screen

        printf("Analog readings = %f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",\
         analog_reading1, analog_reading2, analog_reading3, analog_reading4,\
         analog_reading5, analog_reading6, analog_reading7, analog_reading8);


        printf("Digital inputs: %x\n", digital_in);


        // --- output test ---
        // 
        TOP16II_setDigital(fd, output_count, 0);    // Turn an output OFF

        if (output_count >= 8)
        {
            // last output reached ?, go back to 1
            //
            output_count = 0;
        }   
        output_count++;                             // next output

        TOP16II_setDigital(fd, output_count, 1);    // Turn an output ON    



        usleep(100000);
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

# オイラはその TOP16II を持っていませんのでコード読んだだけですが

えー全部解説しろってことですか？　本が数冊書けちゃう分量っすよ？　それに実行結果はあなたの回路次第で違うっす。とりあえず重要なとこだけ

> `#define DEVICE ("/dev/ttyUSB0")`

TOP16II を接続すると `/dev/ttyUSB0` というデバイスファイルが出現するので、これに対して `write()` や `read()` すると通信できる、ということのようです。複数個の USB 装置が接続されているとき `/dev/ttyUSB1` や `/dev/ttyUSB2` のようにデバイスが複数見える場合があり、それは各ユーザーの接続方法等で異なるはずなので、あなたの実験機で TOP16II のデバイス名が何になっているかを確認し、ソースコードを修正する必要があります。ないしはプログラム外からデバイス名を与えることができるようにしておくとよいです。

`TOP16II_readAnalog()` や `TOP16II_setDigital()`

とりあえずブラックボックスとして使ってみてください。単に使うだけなら関数内部の詳細を理解する必要はないです。なんとなく使ってみたらなんとなく動くはず。関数名からして

- `TOP16II_readAnalog()` はアナログ入力部の値を返し、それを `printf()` しているので Linux のコンソール画面上にアナログ値が出力されます。まともに動かすには適切な入力が必要です。
- `TOP16II_setDigital()` はデジタル出力の状態を変えるようです。その結果を確認するには適切な負荷とオシロスコープが必要です。

ということでハードウエアを操作する際には適切な回路や測定機器が必要で、何もなしにやみくもに手を付けても単に装置を壊すだけになりかねません。まあがんばってください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．このサンプルコードに適切な値，デバイス名などを書き込み，プログラム中に組み込めば装置へのデジタル信号指令，トリガー出力は可能でしょうか？

Comment: `TOP16II_setDigital()` をうまく使えば信号出力はできるでしょう（前準備後始末のコードは当然必要）相手に信号が正しく伝わる回路が書ける前提ですが。あと、信号のタイミングが重要なら（１桁 usec の精度が必要とか）この方法では無理なので、要求次第っす。

Comment: ありがとうございます．担当と相談してみます．